# python playing a file that of which name is a string that chances

Tags: python

There seems to be 2 problems in the code. The len and also the file name "function".

```
import winsound

z = 1

while z == z:

    print("What you want to say (q to quit):")
    say = input()

    if say != "q":

        b = 0

        while b < len(say):
            sound = say[b]
            winsound.PlaySound("r'C:\TALKER\sounds\"+sound+"+".wav", winsound.SND_FILENAME) # 1/4  /   0.25 sec
            b= b + 1
    else:
        SystemExit()
```

Comment: It would help if you said 1) what you want this program to do, and 2) what it is doing instead.

Comment: It suppose to speak sentence that is written. I recorded with audacity sounds of each letter as for example a.wav, b.wav, ...

Comment: But now it plays system sound as many time as there are number of letters

Comment: Well, isn't that what you wanted?  The `PlaySound()` call is in a loop, after all...

Answer (score 1):

```
winsound.PlaySound("r'C:\TALKER\sounds\"+sound+"+".wav",
winsound.SND_FILENAME) # 1/4  /   0.25 sec
```

That string is malformed.  There's a single quote near the beginning, there's confusion about the backslashes, and the "r" is *inside* the string, which you certainly don't want.

It's much simpler to use *forward* slashes for directories.  They work just fine, and there's no trickiness with escaping.  Try this instead:

```
winsound.PlaySound("C:/TALKER/sounds/" + sound + ".wav",
winsound.SND_FILENAME) # 1/4  /   0.25 sec
```